# I can't install apps using apt-get

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I run  debian 5.04 VMware image.
I tried to install the app as

```
  apt-get install tcpdump
```

I got the following:
[image: errors]

I don't know what to do.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to do what it tells you to? "maybe run `apt-get update`"?

Comment: are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as it says. run the following:

`apt-get update
apt-get install --fix-missing`

**UPDATE**: this is not the correct forum for asking questions related to `linux`. Go to [askubuntu.com](http://www.askubuntu.com)

Comment: "apt-get update" also said "404 not found" for some urls. But okay, I will look for some Linux Debian forums

Comment: then try to change your Download Server. I recently ran ito a similar condition but after I changed the download server, the problem was fixed.

Comment: I don't know what is "download server". Is it in VMWare or in Debian?

Comment: it is in debian. `apt-get` downloads files from a server. In yours, I find it to be `us.debian.org`. Try to change it. I havenot used `Debian` so I have no idea. But in ubuntu, I could change it from `software update properties`.